# JSON to Java conversion using GSON throws error

Tags: java, apache-spark, gson, unmarshalling, android

In my spark code I have gson, that is stored in string RDD which I am converting into key and value.

```
JavaPairRDD<String, ArrayList<Guid>> docPairRDD = docRDD.mapToPair(SparkCustomFunctions.generateKeyValuePair());

    /**
     * @return new Tuple with key is of type String and value is of type ArrayList<DocId>
     */
    public static PairFunction<String, String, ArrayList<DocId>> generateKeyValuePair() {
        return new PairFunction<String, String, ArrayList<DocId>>(){

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 9086064488812696200L;
        public Tuple2<String, ArrayList<DocId>> call(String t)
                    throws Exception {

            GsonBuilder gson = new GsonBuilder();
            Document tempObj = gson.create().fromJson(t, Document.class);

        return new Tuple2<String, ArrayList<DocId>>(tempObj.getKey(),(ArrayList<DocId>) tempObj.getEventFields());
            }
        };
    }
}
```

---

### Below are the classes descriptions used in above function

(1).

```
public class Document implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
     @SerializedName("key")
    String key;
     @SerializedName("eventFields")
    List<DocId> eventFields= new ArrayList<DocId>();

    public Document (String key, List<DocId> eventFields) {
        super();
        this.key = key;
        this.eventFields= eventFields;
    }

Its setter and getter
}
```

---

(2).

```
public class DocId implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    String DocId = "";
    String cType = "";
    String events;
    public DocId(String docId, String cType, String eType){
        super();
        this.DocId = docId;
        this.cType = cType;
        this.events = eType;
    }
their setters and getters
}
```

---

But I am getting following error
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 2
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:813)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:689)

I am new at gsona and spark. So please let me know what am I doing wrong?

---

I am storing following type of json into RDD

```
{
  "key": "01key",
  "eventFields": [
    {
      "guid": "abc12",
      "contentType": "dummyContent",
      "events": "dummyEvents"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: *"End of input at line 1 column 2"* sounds like your string is actually just `{`, not the entire JSON you showed. **Debug** your code to confirm value being parsed.

Comment: Also your DocId class properties should also have @SerializedName annotations to match the JSON

Comment: Hello Daniel, My inner json is matching at the class. This is how the input json looks like.                                                                                             {
  "key": "01key",
  "eventFields": [
    {
      "DocId": "abc12",
      "cType": "dummyContent",
      "events": "dummyEvents"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: @Andreas, I am not sure about your suggestion. I saw my input file and it is       of { "key":"Value", "eventFields":[ { "DocId":"dummy1","cType":"dummyC","events":"dummyE"},{.......},{.........}]}

Comment: @user2844511 Your file may have that content, but what is the value of `t` when you call `fromJson()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out the issue, before storing my response I am doing prettyprint so the json is breaking to multiple line and while reading this json, I am assuming the each line is complete json, so I got error. I removed prettyprint and my code started working fine.